# Nest aggregation returns error {Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /people/_search?typed_keys=true}

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm performing a simple aggregation query on elastic search using nest asp per the documentation on getting started. However i get the error `{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /people/_search?typed_keys=true}`. I am using nest 7.0.0. with an elasticsearch cloud service with is elasticsearch 7.0.0. The code below illustrates how i have setup the elasticclient, and how i am performing the query.

I have used the same connection to perform a successfull query operation, hence i think my connection is okay, and the index setup is also okay.

```cs
var settings = new ConnectionSettings("my_elasticsearch_url").DefaultIndex("people");

ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

Person person = new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "George",
                LastName = "Ouma"
            };

            var indexResponse = elasticClient.IndexDocument(person);

            var searchResponse = elasticClient.SearchAsync<Person>(s =>
                s.Size(0)

                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m=>m
                        .Field(f=>f.FirstName)
                        .Query("George")
                    )
                )
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .Terms("first_names", ta => ta
                        .Field(f => f.FirstName)
                    )
                )
            ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();            

var aggregations = searchResponse.Aggregations.Terms("first_names");
```

I expect the aggregate results, but i get `null` and on inspection the `searchResponse` object, i get the error message `{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /people/_search?typed_keys=true}`

Comment: May you share your index mapping? I think the problem here is the field you use for terms aggregation `first_names`, try to use `first_names.keyword`.

Comment: Hey, @Rob, thanks for taking time to look at this. I am using the default index mapping ("people") as indicated in the source.
here is the full code for the one file console app. do you mind having a look? Maybe you mean something else. https://github.com/georgeouma/elasticsearch_gettingstarted

Comment: Also, i used `first_names` in this case to refer to the aggregate name, rather than the fields, could this be wrong usage?

Comment: ah, right, so you need to go with `.Field(f => f.FirstName.Suffix("keyword"))`.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, `.Field(f=>f.FirstName.Suffix("keyword"))` resolves the error. You are awesome, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rob, will you add it to accepted answers, or should i add the answer on your behalf? which i already have :)

Comment: If you need to understand why it wasn't working I recommend you to read these: [1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#CO140-1) and [2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html#_default_mapping_for_string_properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits to @Rob, the solution to this problem is to add the suffix `keyword` to the field as follows:  `.Field(f => f.FirstName.Suffix("keyword"))`